# start app on a different layout each time?

Tags: layout, random, android-studio

I want the app when it is executed to start a different layout, I have this code that allows me to choose the layout where to start but want it to be random thanks.

```
myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

PD: excuse my English, not speaking, he used the translator

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java's built-in [pseudo random number generator](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html) to get a random value in a defined range. Use this to choose a random value for `setCurrentItem`. For example:

```
Random r = new Random();
int randomValue = r.nextInt( 5 );
myPager.setCurrentItem( randomValue );
```

The value you pass to the `nextInt` method is **one more** than the maximum integer you want to receive; the example above will return a random value between 0 and 4 (excluding 5).